# Beautiful Soup: getting contents of all <tag> in xml-ish file

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I've got an xml-ish file I'm trying to parse with BeautifulSoup with let's say an unknown multiple of tags within the tree of another tag. Things go swimmingly, at least for the first tag I'm  extracting within the set of nexted tags. This isn't really html or xml, but close...

Given the format:

```
<data>
<type>
    <type_attribute_1>1</type_attribute_1>
    <type_attribute_2>2</type_attribute_2>
</type>
<type>
    <type_attribute_1>3</type_attribute_1>
    <type_attribute_2>4</type_attribute_2>
</type>
</data>
```

How might I extract the values of type_attribute_1 and type_attribute_2 for both type tags and assign to a variable -- i.e. "Type_1_attribute_1", "Type_1_attribute_2", "Type_2_attribute_1" & "Type_2_attribute_2"

I'm using code like this, but it only works on the first `<type>` located within the `<data>`:

```
Type_1_Attribute_1 = soup.data.type.type_attribute_1.text
Type_1_Attribute_2 = soup.data.type.type_attribute_2.text
```

***UPDATE***

I think to phrase what I'm looking for a little differently may help. Instead of declaring the variable name Type_1_Attribute_1, as I don't know how many Type siblings there are, tack "_1", "_2", "_3"... on to "Type, for each sibling. i.e.
Assuming:

```
Types = [i.stripText() for i in soup.select('Type')]
parseables = len(Types)
for i in range(0, parseables)
    j = i+1
    Type = Types[i]
    Attribute_1 = Type.Type_Attribute_1.text 
    print Attribute_1
```

Which prints the value of Attribute_1 for each Type, How would I add "Type_j" in Attribute_1 to be filled in with j's value?

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that the 2nd and 3rd line of data, do not have any data in between the brackets, But inside of the bracket....

Comment: That was just an error here, and is now fixed.

Comment: Show an accurate sample of your input document (the one you show _is_ XML, as far as I can see). Show a complete sample of your Python code and also show more explicitly what you need as the output. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: By XML-ish, I mean it does not have an XML declaration and, for the purposes of clarity, i opted for a generic example representative of the input file. I'll add a bit more, but try to get the concept over the details.

Answer (score 2):

What about this-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data  = """<data>
<type>
    <type_attribute_1>1</type_attribute_1>
    <type_attribute_2>2<2/type_attribute_2>
</type>
<type>
    <type_attribute_1>3</type_attribute_1>
    <type_attribute_2>4</type_attribute_2>
</type>
</data>"""

soup = bs(data,'lxml')

Type_1_Attribute_1 = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('type_attribute_1')]
Type_1_Attribute_2 = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('type_attribute_2')]

print filter(bool,Type_1_Attribute_1)
print filter(bool,Type_1_Attribute_2)
```

Output-

```
[u'1', u'3']
[u'2', u'4']
```

---

EDIT
I do not get you, why you need this where looping over the list itself a variable (iterator)- e.g

```
for i in Type_1_Attribute_1:
    print (i)# here i itself a variable and it changes when i reiterate
```

Prints-

```
1
3
```

So if you need to use every item from that list just use iterator and pass to a function as i passed to `print` function.

Comment: Very Helpful -- This returns the values of a list, which I can access and assign values from to a variable with var = Type_1_Attribute_1[i]. Now is there a good way to count the number of data tags so that I may assign a value to a numbered variable? i.e. var1 = Type_1_Attribute_1[0], var2 =Type_2_Attribute_1[0] , foo1 = Type_1_Attribute_2[0], foo2 = Type_2_Attribute_2[1]?